# Decimal.Parse and incorrect string format error

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I have a simple problem with decimal parsing. The following code works fine on my computer but when I publish the project on the server (VPS, Windows Server 2008 R2 standard edition) I get the error "Input string was in incorrect format." Any ideas what's wrong?

I store that parsed number in the MySQL DB table - the column type is `DECIMAL(10, 4)`

**Source Code:**

```
CultureInfo nonInvariantCulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU"); //or pl-PL
nonInvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = nonInvariantCulture;
string toConvert = ("3,4589").Replace(",", "."); //it's an example
decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(toConvert);
```

Comment: Are you sure the machine in question has en-AU (or pl_PL) cultures installed? On a fresh install, most machines have only the english subsets installed by default.

Comment: whether is this windows or web application ?

Comment: Ramesh Muthiah >> it's web application

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you know that the string representation of the number uses comma as the decimal separator you can parse the value using a custom `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
var number = "3,4589";
var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," };
var value = Decimal.Parse(number, numberFormatInfo);
```

You can also use an existing `CultureInfo` for a culture that you know will work like `pl-PL` but I think this is easier to understand.

If on the other hand the format of the number is `3.4589` you can simply use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which you can consider a kind of "default" culture based on `en-US`:

```
var number = "3.4589";
var value = Decimal.Parse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess for a work around the below code will sort it out the problem.

```
decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(toConvert, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can build a custom `NumberFormatInfo` to parse your value

something on these lines

```
NumberFormatInfo numinf = new NumberFormatInfo();
numinf.NumberDecimalSeparator= ",";    
decimal.Parse("3,4589", numinf);
```