# FormatException - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sql, string

In my SQL Server Management Studio, one of the tables (ACTION_LOCATION_MAP) I created has the following design:

[image: ACTION_LOCATION_MAP]

And in one of my functions I am making a call to a stored procedure to retrieve all records that have the matching `ActionId` that I'm passing to the function.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMapCoordinates]
@ActionId NVARCHAR(20)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ACTION_LOCATION_MAP
    WHERE ActionId = @ActionId
END
```

Function (C#):

```
public IEumerable<MapCoordinate> GetActionMapCoordinates(string id)
{
    /* Here a call is made to the stored procedure and the matching records are
       returned. Truncating other parts of the code for brevity. */
    ....
    cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ActionId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20) { Value = id });
    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var coordinate = new MapCoordinate
        {
            Map_Location_Id    = int.Parse(dr["MapLocationId"].ToString()),
            Action_Id          = dr["ActionId"].ToString(),
            Location_Title     = dr["LocationTitle"].ToString(),
            Location_Latitude  = decimal.Parse(dr["Latitude"].ToString()),
            Location_Longitude = decimal.Parse(dr["Longitude"].ToString()),
            Shape_Group_Id     = int.Parse(dr["ShapeGroupId"].ToString()),
            Shape_Group_Order  = int.Parse(dr["ShapeGroupOrder"].ToString())
        };
        coordinates.Add(coordinate);
    }
    // rest of the code truncated
}
```

When the function is called, I get the following error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format. System.FormatException

   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at (/* namespace intentionally hidden */).GetActionMapCoordinates(String id)
   at (/* namespace intentionally hidden */).LocationController.MapCoordinatesById(String id)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}
```

My hunch is that the decimal values might not have been converted properly, but being a novice (at best) at SQL, I've been wrestling with this one for hours now. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: simple question..have you used the debugger..? which line is it throwing the error on ..

Comment: It looks like a parsing issue. Try to use a CultureInfo parameter in your call to Parse () corresponding to the number format stored in ddbb.. Otherwise remove columns from the query till you find the ofending one ;-)

Comment: Also, don use * in your queries, it's evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have a null value in one of the last two columns.  In that case, `dr["Column"].ToString()` will return a string that cannot be parsed.

Note that the stack trace mentions System.Number.ParseInt32, which points to your last two columns.

To solve the problem, you need to decide what to do when the db column is null.  If the Shape_Group_Id and Shape_Group_Order properties are nullable, there's not much to decide, of course, but if they are not, you may need to redesign a bit.

Comment: +1 because I agree and I referenced your answer in mine.

Comment: @MelvinSmith but your code doesn't compile -- dr.IsDBNull takes an int argument.

Comment: @phoog - You nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you hinted, you may be trying to parse a decimal value with Int32.Parse(), so find that out by debugging.

Otherwise, I also recommend not converting to String only to immediately convert to Int, because the SQL driver may already have the number in object format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a snippet, from memory, that may help, it will default values that are either null objects, or DBNull to 0.

```
Map_Location_Id    = dr["MapLocationId"] != DBNull.Value ?
                           System.Convert.ToInt32(dr["MapLocationId"]) : default(int),
```

NOTE: Update, since phoog pointed out a good point, null value handling, add in code to deal with that.

Comment: +1 for mentioning DBNull.Value. I tore my hair over a similar issue for a while until I found out that a null value from a data reader is DBNull.Value and DBNull.Value != null.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is since the `ShapeGroupID` and `ShapeGroupOrder` fields allow `null` values, you are trying to parse null value to int , which results in an exception to be thrown.

Better use TryParse:

```
int x;
if (TryParse(dr["ShapeGroupId"].ToString(),ref x )
{
 Shape_Group_Id =x;
}
```

Comment: phoog beat you to it, but my upvote for a great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as 2nd parameter or else you can add NumberFormatInfo for custom format.
var value = Decimal.Parse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897134/c-sharp-decimal-parse-and-incorrect-string-format-error)